# GoogleScript stopping at random and not completing its given task to sort through a response sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have this script pulling from a response sheet and running an if statement on each response to check what type of response it is at the current moment I have to types it checks for one being "Register a new Fox" and "Submit a Transaction" I'm pretty new to googlescripts with a decent knowledge of other languages. I'm looking for a solution for why my loop is stopping and how it can be fixed rather, any examples will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

```
function SetCellData() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  
  var debugSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Debug")
  var famTree = ss.getSheetByName("Family")
  var transaction = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions")
  var sheetMaster = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses")
  
  debugSheet.getRange("Debug!A1").setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!C2").getValue());
  debugSheet.getRange("Debug!A2").setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!C:C").getLastRow());
  
  var mainRange = sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!B2:B");
  
  var registeredFoxes = 0
  var transactionsMade = 0
  
  for (i=2; i <= sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!C:C").getLastRow();i++){
    
//    Checks to see if they are trying to add a new fox.
    if (sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!C" + i.toString()).getValue() == "Register a New Fox"){
      famTree.getRange("Family!B"+(6+registeredFoxes)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!D" + i.toString()).getValue());
      famTree.getRange("Family!C"+(6+registeredFoxes)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!E" + i.toString()).getValue());
      famTree.getRange("Family!D"+(6+registeredFoxes)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!F" + i.toString()).getValue());
      famTree.getRange("Family!E"+(6+registeredFoxes)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!G" + i.toString()).getValue());
      famTree.getRange("Family!H"+(6+registeredFoxes)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!H" + i.toString()).getValue());
      registeredFoxes = registeredFoxes + 1;
//      Checks to see if they are submiting a transaction.
    }else if (sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!C" + i.toString()).getValue() == "Submit a Transaction"){
      transaction.getRange("Transactions!E"+(8+transactionsMade)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!I" + i.toString()).getValue());
      transaction.getRange("Transactions!F"+(8+transactionsMade)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!L" + i.toString()).getValue());
      if (sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!J" + i.toString()).getValue() == "Profit"){
        transaction.getRange("Transactions!C"+(8+transactionsMade)).setValue("+");
        transaction.getRange("Transactions!D"+(8+transactionsMade)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!K" + i.toString()).getValue());
      }else{
        transaction.getRange("Transactions!C"+(8+transactionsMade)).setValue("-");
        transaction.getRange("Transactions!D"+(8+transactionsMade)).setValue("-"+ sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!K" + i.toString()).getValue());
      }
      transaction.getRange("Transactions!B"+(8+transactionsMade)).setValue(sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!M" + i.toString()).getValue());
      transactionsMade = transactionsMade + 1
      }else{
      debugSheet.getRange("Debug!A3").setValue(registeredFoxes);
    }
  }
  famTree.getRange("Family!B2").setValue("Fox Family Members:\n" + registeredFoxes)
  transaction.getRange("Transactions!B4").setValue("Transactions Made:\n" + transactionsMade)
  
}
```

Comment: View >executions

Comment: Also implement logs for troubleshooting - e.g. log `i` in each loop to see where it stops, and also log something in the `if` statements to see which statement is entered.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can speed things up is to get all the data out of all 3 sheet tabs, manipulate the data in the 2D arrays, and then set the new values all at once.  Currently you are getting and setting values on every iteration of the loop, so there are read and write operations happening constantly which takes time.  You need to read all the data once, and write all the data once.

The loop might be terminating for some reason.  And the only reason it might be doing that is if the count hits the last row number, or there is an error in your code:

I would change:

```
for (i=2; i <= sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!C:C").getLastRow();i++){
```

To:

```
var L = sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!C:C").getLastRow();
Logger.log("L: " + L)

for (i=2; i<=L;i++){
```

Comment: I think it's definitely a step in the right direction but it's as slow as a turtle and to run through about 80 lines of responses it takes it on average 260 seconds, which is about 3.25 seconds per response. In my opinion that is very slow.

From what I've heard is that there are reasons for it taking this long because of the way I'm scanning through it but I'm not exactly sure how to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but it's not orthodox any adjustments that could be made let me know

Pretty much it was taking to much effort and memory to find the fields that I keep calling so I got all of them at once and then ran statements off that.

```
function SetCellData() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  
  var debugSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Debug")
  var family = ss.getSheetByName("Family")
  var transaction = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions")
  var sheetMaster = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses")
  
//  Starts from Row 2 Column C
  var vA=sheetMaster.getRange(2, 3,(sheetMaster.getLastRow()-1),(sheetMaster.getLastColumn()-2)).getValues();
  var lastColumn = sheetMaster.getLastColumn()
  
  var registeredFoxes = 0
  var transactionsMade = 0
  var slotsScanned = 0
  
  var L = sheetMaster.getRange("Form Responses!C:C").getLastRow();
  Logger.log("L: " + L)

  for (i=2; i<=L;i++){
//    Checks to see if they are trying to add a new fox.
    if (vA[i-2][0] == "Register a New Fox"){
      for (j=1;j<=5;j++){
        if (j==5){
          family.getRange(registeredFoxes+6,j+3).setValue(vA[i-2][j]);
        }else{
          family.getRange(registeredFoxes+6,j+1).setValue(vA[i-2][j]);
        }
      }
      registeredFoxes ++

//      Checks to see if they are submiting a transaction.
    }else if (vA[i-2][0] == "Submit a Transaction"){
      for (j=7; j<=11;j++){
        transaction.getRange(transactionsMade+8,j-5).setValue(vA[i-2][j-1]);
        if (vA[i-2][j-1] == "Profit"){
          transaction.getRange(transactionsMade+8,j-5).setValue("+");
        }else if (vA[i-2][j-1] == "Loss"){
          transaction.getRange(transactionsMade+8,j-5).setValue("-");
        }else if (j == 9 && vA[i-2][7] == "Loss"){
          transaction.getRange(transactionsMade+8,j-5).setValue("-" + vA[i-2][j-1]);
        }
      }
      transactionsMade ++
    }else{
      Logger.log("Tried to read something...")
    }
  }
  family.getRange(2,2).setValue("Fox Family Members:\n" + registeredFoxes);
  transaction.getRange(4,2).setValue("Transactions Made:\n" + transactionsMade);
  
}
```